# Running time of while loop pseudo code

Tags: time-complexity

```
s = n
while (s>1)

if (s is even)
s = s/2

else
s = s+1
```

I know that it's O(logn) if the code halves s every time, but I'm not sure how the if even/else statement changes anything. Thanks

Comment: Try a variety of numbers. Use 111, for example. You'll be surprised at how fast this algorithm goes.

Comment: I can't give you the O notation but basically it will half every two runs of the algorithm as opposed to every run.

Comment: @Compass yea i ran the code before i posted the question. I could explain it with mere words I just have no clue how to give a formal running time